# Azure ServiceBus attach attribute to message when autoforwarding

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

Is it possible to attach certain attribute to each message that is auto forwarded? Or perhaps when the message is finally received see from where it has been forwarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. Auto-forwarding is defined on an entity level, but solely as an entity to forward to. Properties modification (Actions) can be only done with Rules only (on subscriptions) on the broker side.

Comment: Not what I have asked for but rules on subscriptions will do what I actually need!